# How to trigger ng-repeat in Angularjs with MVC application..?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing

i'm creating an application in AngularJS with MVC
i write code in AdminCtrl.js is:

```
var adminModule = angular.module('angApp', []);
 adminModule.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
 function ($scope, $http) {
    //*****get data from  Product table
    $scope.products = {};
    GetAdmin();
    function GetAdmin() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Admin/GetAdmin',
            datatype:'HTML',
        }).success(function data() {
            $scope.products = data.result;
        })
    }
}]);
```

i'm able to get data as collection from back end now using $scope i'm binding it to my view as:

```
<div id="divTest" ng-controller="AdminCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in products">
        Prod_ID:{{item.Prod_ID}}
        Prod_Name:{{item.Prod_Name}}
        Prod_Price:{{item.Prod_Price}}
        Prod_Desc:{{item.Prod_Desc}}
    </div>
</div>
```

on the view i'm not able to bind this data using ng-repeat, but this data is visible on console.
please any one help me to figure out the issue what i'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `datatype:'HTML',`

Comment: i did it with JSON or HTML, also tried without datatype, it doesn't work.

Comment: what u get on `console.log ?`

Comment: returning data from from function, now i want to render it on view but doesn't work fine

Comment: can u print the data in view like `{{ products | json }}` ?

Comment: i also tried this,

couldn't fix my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
..  }).success(function data() {
                $scope.products = data.result;
            })..
```

to

```
..  }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.products = data.result;
            })..
```

ie:

```
   var adminModule = angular.module('angApp', []);
     adminModule.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
     function ($scope, $http) {
        //*****get data from  Product table
        $scope.products = {};
        GetAdmin();
        function GetAdmin() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/Admin/GetAdmin',
                datatype:'HTML',
    //data needs to be inside bracket
            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.products = data.result;
            })
        }

}]);
```

Comment: yes, using this now i'm able to see data in message alert but this is not rendering on view

Comment: <div id="divTest" ng-controller="AdminCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in products">
            Prod_ID:{{item.Prod_ID}}
            Prod_Name:{{item.Prod_Name}}
            Prod_Price:{{item.Prod_Price}}
            Prod_Desc:{{item.Prod_Desc}}
        </div>
    </div>

please let me know what i'm missing here

Comment: @Amitavin add this to your html   <div id="divTest" ng-controller="AdminCtrl"> ***<pre>{{products | json}}</pre>*** that allows you see all your products

Comment: @Amitavin can you see any data ?

Comment: yes i'm seeing data when i alert it as:

.success(function (data) {
                $scope.products = data.result;
                alert(data);
            })

but it not rendering on view

Comment: in that case change $scope.products = data.result; to $scope.products = data

Comment: try this  $scope.products = data.data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63931/discussion-between-sylwester-and-amitavin).

Answer (score 2):

i did only a little bit mistake, i was binding ng-app to  but in the sense it should be bind with  now it's working.

my new code like as  .....

```
   <body ng-app="angApp">
   <script src="Scripts/app/AdminCtrl.js"></script>

   <div id="alert" class="alert"></div>
   <div ng-controller="AdminCtrl">

        <div class="admin-login">
            <h2>using angularjs</h2>
            <input type="text" id="txtUserAng" placeholder="User Name" ng-model="U_Name" />
            <input type="password" id="txtPWDAng" placeholder="Password" ng-model="U_PWD" />
            <input type="button" id="login" value="login" ng-click="Login()" />

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```